# How to integrate iOS app with playback controls in lock screen and bottom panel?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, media-player

I want to use Play/Stop, Next, Prev buttons, seeker & show album arts in "standard" iOS user interface, just like many other apps.

What classes should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPNowPlayingInfoCenter_Class/) for setting the current album art.

And you can use `- (void) remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)event` for handeling the playback controls.
This is all explained in [Remote Control Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html)

A simple search on Google would have found this.